# query not working in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I run this on my local machine it works fine...but when I upload to heroku
I get an error 500 something when wrong

settings controller

class SettingsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :confirm_logged_in

```
def company
  @company = User.company
  @user_id = session[:user_id]
  @user_name = session[:name]
  @companies = Company.where(:user_id => @user_id)
end
```

end

---

setting view

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <div id="media">
    <span class="lop">    
        <%= image_tag company.logo.url (:small)  %>
    </span>
```

### <% end>

I check heroku logs this is what I get...any ideas

```
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/settings/company" for 69.137
.99.169 at Fri Feb 18 01:09:24 -0800 2011
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by SettingsController#company
 as HTML
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: /app/928a2790-dfe4-4726-8793-1fa99837495b/
home/app/views/settings/company.html.erb:14: warning: don't put space before arg
ument parentheses
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: Rendered settings/_menu.html.erb (2.1ms)
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: Rendered settings/company.html.erb within
layouts/application (6.8ms)
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: Completed   in 22ms
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERRO
R:  operator does not exist: text = integer
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...ompanies".* FROM "companies" WH
ERE "companies"."user_id" = 3
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:
                          ^
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name
and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WH
ERE "companies"."user_id" = 3):
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:     8:       
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:     9:     
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:     10:     
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:     11:     
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:     12:       
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:     13:         
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:     14:             
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/settings/company.html.erb:11:i
n `_app_views_settings_company_html_erb___121502233_23577600314100_0'
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 app[web.1]:
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 heroku[router]: GET miso3.heroku.com/settings/company
dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=36ms bytes=934
2011-02-18T01:09:24-08:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /settings/company HTTP/1.1 | 69.137
.99.169 | 965 | http | 500
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/settings/company" for 69.137
.99.169 at Fri Feb 18 01:33:03 -0800 2011
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by SettingsController#company
 as HTML
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]: Rendered settings/_menu.html.erb (1.5ms)
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]: Rendered settings/company.html.erb within
layouts/application (3.9ms)
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]: Completed   in 5ms
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERRO
R:  operator does not exist: text = integer
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...ompanies".* FROM "companies" WH
ERE "companies"."user_id" = 3
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:
                          ^
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name
and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WH
ERE "companies"."user_id" = 3):
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:     8:       
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:     9:     
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:     10:     
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:     11:     
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:     12:       
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:     13:         
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:     14:             
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/settings/company.html.erb:11:i
n `_app_views_settings_company_html_erb___121502233_23577600314100_0'
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 app[web.1]:
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 heroku[router]: GET miso3.heroku.com/settings/company
dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=20ms bytes=934
2011-02-18T01:33:03-08:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /settings/company HTTP/1.1 | 69.137
.99.169 | 965 | http | 500
```

Comment: so it turns out when I did the migration to add the foreign key to company table....I miss type integer to interger for user_id and in development I use sqlite which is pretty forgiven but PostgreSQL is NOT....so thanks to anyone that look at this...and sorry for wasting your time

Comment: you'd be better matching your development DB to Postgresql83 to match Heroku so you don't get caught out again - we've been caught a few times but now use the same PG for development to make sure we don't again!